# mixing Intel CPU of same FCLGA socket type and scalability?

Tags: central-processing-unit, intel

I have a 4 socket server, calling for FCLGA 2011-3.
It was built using four Intel E5-4667v3 (16 cores).

If one cpu fails, can it be replaced with **one** E5-4667v4 (18 cores) and still work with the 3 original E5-4667v3 CPU's ?

Or all cpu's required to be the exact same, and if so can someone reference manufacturer documentation?

Sorting through available Intel CPU's that are all FCLGA2011-3 and wondering if I can mix & match any as long as everything is socket=2011-3 and scalability = 4S or S4S ?

Comment: All same, and same clock speed.

Comment: Unlikely, but it worths a nice try. Except if it is used by paying customers, then it likely doesn't worth.